# Frames does not reload

Tags: javascript

There are two frames in my web page. The frames load the same file (php). This file has this code:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);
```

On my localhost it works fine. Online works too, but sometimes, the one frame stops to reload and the other reloads.

Do you think that internet connection affect it? 
Maybe is something else.

Comment: Try using jsFiddle.net and see what happens there

Comment: It is a big project and i can to do that!
Do you know what error the "location.reload(true);" throw?

Comment: See my answer hope it works! Please upvote & mark correct if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why:

> setInterval() - executes a function, over and over again, at specified
> time intervals
>
> setTimeout() - executes a function, once, after waiting
> a specified number of milliseconds

```
setInterval(test,1000);

function test(){
 console.log("TEST");
}
```

Now test will be printed every 1000ms!

Please use setInterval instead!